# How can I force the object has any property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
type Data = Record<string, string | number | boolean | null>;
```

Here is my type, but I know I couldn't create rightly.

I want to type an error if I don't crate any property into an object.

```
const object: Data = {} // should give type error
```

I tried some TS Utility Types but i couldn't do it

Comment: Not possible unless you know the property names beforehand.

Comment: There's no specific type that works this way; you could make a generic type that acts as a helper, so `const object = asData({x: "abc"})` would succeed but `const object = asData({})` would fail, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0z2Rw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *specific* `ValidData` type in TypeScript that corresponds exactly to "an object of type `Data` that contains at least one property".  So we won't be able to write code like `const obj1: ValidData = {⋯}` and have it work.  That is, you'd *like* to write

```
const obj1: ValidData = { okay: 123 }; // okay
const obj2: ValidData = { okay: 456, ok: 789 }; // okay
const obj3: ValidData = {}; // error!
```

but there's no `ValidData` that works the way you want in general.

---

However, you can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `ValidData<T>` type that acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a type `T` such that `T extends ValidData<T>` if and only if `T` has at least one property and is of type `Data`.  Like this:

```
type ValidData<T extends Data> =
    T & (keyof T extends never ? { needAtLeastOneProperty: "oops" } : unknown);
```

That uses a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check whether `T` has any known keys, by comparing [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) `T` to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  If it has keys, then `ValidData<T>` is `T & unknown` which is just `T` ([the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) is absorbed by [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)), so `T extends ValidData<T>` is true.   If it doesn't, then `ValidData<T>` is `T & { needAtLeastOneProperty: "oops" }`, and since `T` doesn't have a `needAtLeastOneProperty` property, then `T extends ValidData<T>` is false:

```
type Okay = ValidData<{ okay: number }>;
// type Okay = { okay: number; }
type AlsoOkay = ValidData<{ okay: number, ok: number }>;
// type AlsoOkay = { okay: number, ok: number };
type NotOkay = ValidData<{}>;
// type NotOkay = { needAtLeastOneProperty: "oops"; }
```

We don't want to have to write redundant things like

```
const obj1: ValidData<{okay: number}> = {okay: 123};
```

So we'll want to use a generic helper function that *infers* the type `T` for us:

```
const asValidData = <T extends Data>(t: ValidData<T>) => t;
```

Which we can use as follows:

```
const obj1 = asValidData({ okay: 123 }); // okay
const obj2 = asValidData({ okay: 456, ok: 789 }); // okay
const obj3 = asValidData({}); // error! 
// --------------------> ~~
// Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '{ needAtLeastOneProperty: "oops"; }'.
```

You can see how the invalid empty object is rejected with an error message that is hopefully understandable to the developer.

So there you go.  Note that we are writing `const obj1 = asValidData({⋯})` instead of the desired `const obj1: ValidData = {⋯}`, but that actually isn't very different if you squint at it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGilIpqgB8pKBXAWwCMJdWUHtmwAbCHEqDOo0QD4A3AFgAUKtCQoANTijy+eIkIAVKBAAewCJXzFYCOHJSqorqKYBkUABQBrCCDYAGbuZpbWtuwQAG78UAD8UADeURD4AILAADISpADylBAACrjYkLigAFxQAEQiYMQ1UAC+UNUclL6U2ADulACUymoqGtB5vnAgKNq6+oZwhCnYEyDVnLxxzYqqAPQ7UKNQ45PTSytr3Hy4Ci3q4NDposTYx1OoOnoGDotQy5MXG1w9GWAKuLW2Kj2B3uUEez1ep1+53Yl34wN8oM2Q0OADlsMAEe9Zl8jEktkMobj8YTkqkMtlcgTCiUyvwqrV6o0bs1VLyVDhKKQoHBiB85g5piYwlYbHZ5nJvMBqmKSQtjHJ+ignMAhqoBULsDwAFYARmmIpV828Z3+UBNACYAMwtQZ67CC4C-Y3282i4lWm2rKAAFgArAA2dHVADsAA4AJwuob6z2Go3O1AW-0Oa3NQZQKH8Uq4ACEUF2+wAtNWa7W63WnAA-RsV2G4ajcaypkKHADkZN7UHIdm6npFxHI1EocB44gO2CgYDguDgXAgVgEwWhmn7dMyORFTOKpXK7LqZS5LV7ADpVEA)

Comment: this usage solved my problem thank you very much